# "In App Purchasing" still wont work after trying all these steps

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

i have carried out these several steps for five non consumable in app purchases to be available within my app but still nothing is showing up when i go to the TableViewController that i linked the IAP code to... (i would also like to give a big thanks to the tutorial i followed which has got me this far by raywenderlich)

- -Made a new app ID
- -Successfully followed all the steps for linking and downloading certificates
- Changed the bundle ID on xcode for my project to the one i made for
  my app on IOS developer portal
- -Linked all the devices and made a test user account
- -Made the non consumable IAP on itunes connect and used the Identifiers within the IAP coding
- -Signed my phone out of my itunes account so tht its ready to be used with a test account
- -Coding for the IAP looks to be correct with store kit imported and product identifiers implemented within the .m file
- -Waited 24 hours for the newly created IAP to sync with itunes connect
- -I DIDNT upload the binaries!
- i have hosting with apple turned on but didnt upload anything - could
  this be the issue?
- i deleted the app on my phone and reinstalled for testing but still
  nothing

All i get when i successfull run the build is a page that looks like its loading something but then nothing a blank page that i can pull down to refresh on but still nothing no IAP that i created.

**Any suggestions of what else i can do or add and if you need me to upload all the codes for all the files i can do...**

**coding for IAP within the ViewController.h file**

```
#import "Accounts/Accounts.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface ViewController19 : UITableViewController

@end
```

**Coding for IAP within the ViewController.m file**

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "SecretsIAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface ViewController19 () {
    NSArray *_products;
    NSNumberFormatter * _priceFormatter;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController19

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reload) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self reload];
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

    _priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restore" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(restoreTapped:)];

}

- (void)restoreTapped:(id)sender {
    [[SecretsIAPHelper sharedInstance] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSString * productIdentifier = notification.object;
    [_products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKProduct * product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productIdentifier]) {
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];

}

- (void)reload {
    _products = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [[SecretsIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
        if (success) {
            _products = products;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _products.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;
    [_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

    if ([[SecretsIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
    } else {
        UIButton *buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 37);
        [buyButton setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.accessoryView = buyButton;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    SKProduct *product = _products[buyButton.tag];

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
    [[SecretsIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];

}

@end
```

**Coding for IAP within the IAPHelper.h file**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification;

typedef void (^RequestProductsCompletionHandler)(BOOL success, NSArray * products);

@interface IAPHelper : NSObject

- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers;
- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product;
- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier;
- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions;


@end
```

**Coding for IAP within the IAPHelper.m file**

```
#import "IAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

NSString *const IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification = @"IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification";

// 2
@interface IAPHelper () <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>
@end

// 3
@implementation IAPHelper {
    SKProductsRequest * _productsRequest;
    RequestProductsCompletionHandler _completionHandler;

    NSSet * _productIdentifiers;
    NSMutableSet * _purchasedProductIdentifiers;
}

- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers {

    if ((self = [super init])) {

        // Store product identifiers
        _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;

        // Check for previously purchased products
        _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
        for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers) {
            BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productIdentifier];
            if (productPurchased) {
                [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
                NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            }
        }

        // Add self as transaction observer
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    }
    return self;

}

- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler {


    // 1
    _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

    // 2
    _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
    _productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [_productsRequest start];

}

- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
    return [_purchasedProductIdentifiers containsObject:productIdentifier];
}

- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

    SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }

    _completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
    _completionHandler = nil;

}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    _completionHandler(NO, nil);
    _completionHandler = nil;

}

#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionOBserver

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    NSLog(@"failedTransaction...");
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

    [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier userInfo:nil];

}

- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
@end
```

**Coding for IAP within the SecretsIAPHelper.h file**

```
#import "IAPHelper.h"

@interface SecretsIAPHelper : IAPHelper

+ (SecretsIAPHelper *)sharedInstance;

@end
```

**Coding for IAP within the SecretsIAPHelper.m file**

```
#import "SecretsIAPHelper.h"

@implementation SecretsIAPHelper

+ (SecretsIAPHelper *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static SecretsIAPHelper * sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        NSSet * productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                      @"com.designsbydeondrae.XXXXXXX.remove_ads",
                                      @"com.designsbydeondrae.XXXXXXX.FoundationSkills",
                                      @"com.designsbydeondrae.XXXXXXX.IntermediateSkills",
                                      @"com.designsbydeondrae.XXXXXXX.AllSkills",
                                      @"com.designsbydeondrae.XXXXXXX.AdvancedSkills",
                                      nil];
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}


@end
```

**Coding for IAP within the DetailViewController.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;

@end
```

**Coding for IAP within the DetailViewController.h file**

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

So just to summarise...

- Used StoreKit to access the In-App Purchase APIs and retrieve the
  list which brings up nothing when i run the build
- Specified the product identifiers for my app
- Displaying the products which seems to be an issue though it does
  show a screen like its about to load something then nothing just a
  page with a pull to refresh on it

Comment: What have you been able to tell about what's happening through debugging? Your table view isn't loading anything - well, why is that? What response is it waiting for to load, and what response is it getting?

Comment: delete and reinstall the app, you may still have the old bundle.

Comment: @carlveazey i get that issue that says "Prototype table cells must have reuse identifiers" how do i go on about fixing this? Paul i already tried deleting and reinstalling the app from my phone but still nothing HOWEVER as i made the IAP on itunes connect i clicked on host content with apple but didnt upload anything, could this be the issue aswell? do i have to upload anything at this testing stage?

Comment: Wait are you getting this issue "Prototype table cells must have reuse identifiers" ? That has nothing to do with IAP.

Comment: yes i am getting that issue after i added the table view controller and linked the IAP to that view controller but thus isnt the issue as the build runs fine - if it has nothing to do with it @sbarow then how do i get rid of it and why isnt that view controller returning anything for IAP when i run the project apart from a page that starts off by loading at the top but then returns nothing.... I CAN ADD THE CODING I USED WITHIN ALL THE FILES FOR IAP IF THAT WOULD HELP?

Comment: The reason you are getting this issue  "Prototype table cells must have reuse identifiers" is because you have not set the reuse identifier in Storyboard. Click on the cell and then in the right panel you will see reuse identifier or something.

Comment: Is requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) returning an empty array?

Comment: if you mean returning nothing when i run the build and try load the IAP when you say returning an empty array then yes its returning nothing just a page that has a pull down to refresh on it - if youve had a chance to look through my code above, anything i can improve to make this work? and re use identifiers box in the right panel is empty what should i type or add in their ? which ID @sbarow i appreciate you trying to help btw sir

Comment: Same name as ***UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];*** @"Cell"

Comment: @sbarow i have fixed that thankyou but NOW back to the main issue of not having anything load up for the IAP when i run the build and click on the appropriate screen

Comment: Do these com.designsbydeondrae.XXXXXXX.remove_ads match the items in iTunes Connect?

Comment: @sbarow yes it does match the one in itunes Connect the X's are just for privacy but in xcode i have the right ones matching

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35547/discussion-between-sbarow-and-user2459150)

Comment: This is an absolutely _absurd_ amount of code to expect others to read through and debug. Please pare it down to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any one that finds this post in the future, the reason no items where showing up when requesting IAP was due to content not being uploaded for hosted content.